# Setting converter value to null

Tags: wpf, binding, parameters, null, converters

I have a general function for binding with a converter parameter. When I don't need a converter I want to pass in null but it doesn't let me it says:

```
Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified.
```

Before assigning it in the function i check if the converter was null, but I guess the issue is that `IMultiValueConverter` doesn't accept null as value.

Is there anyway to achieve this, without creating a Converter that just returns the input, or an overloaded method?

```
protected MultiBinding CreateBinding(object source, IMultiValueConverter converter, object parameter, object [] dps)
    {
        MultiBinding multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
        if ( converter != null )
        multiBinding.Converter = converter;
        multiBinding.ConverterParameter = parameter; 
        .....
```

---

In other words I want to simulate a direct property binding without a converter, using the function above.

Answer (score 0):

MultiBindings only make sense if you specify a MultiValueConverter or a StringFormat to define how the output is calculated based on each source.

I'm not sure on what you're trying to achieve, but if you specify an empty StringFormat (string.Empty), you should get no errors, but it won't do anything at runtime.

Comment: I don't want to type four lines every time to set up a binding, it takes too much space. I want a universal function that can create a binding given the four parameters. It can a single binding or a multibinding with parameters. I am not sure what you are refering to when saying StringFormat, you mean pass that as the value to convter.

Comment: Then use a binding when you have only one source, and a multibinding when you have more than one.

Comment: then I would have to have either an overloaded method or two separate methods, because the function will have to either have a single or multibinding return type.

Comment: Or you can return [BindingBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.aspx) which is the base clase for all type of bindings.